# How to get page numbers with small margins

Tags: margins, page-numbering, geometry

I am building a template to output reports and I cannot have the page numbers to show.
I have no requirements but

1. landscape
2. have .5cm for margins (the doc will contain R plots and I want to maximize the plotting area)

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[landscape,
            verbose,
            tmargin=0.5cm,
            bmargin=0.5cm,
            lmargin=0.5cm,
            rmargin=0.5cm,
            showframe]{geometry}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
            pdfusetitle,
            bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksnumbered=true,
            bookmarksopen=true,
            bookmarksopenlevel=2,
            breaklinks=false,
            pdfborder={0 0 1},
            backref=false,
            colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1}}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\pagenumbering{arabic} %numering of table of contents are arabic numbering
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} % Clear the header and footer
\cfoot[R]{\thepage} % Set the right side of the footer to be the page number
\pagestyle{fancy} % Turn on the style

\begin{document}
   Hello world!
\end{document}
```

But I cannot see the page numbers.

EDIT: Is it possible to do it without changing the margins ?

Comment: You not left space for page number. If you increase `bmargin=0.5cm,` to `bmargin=1.5cm,`, you will see it.

Comment: @Zarko, yes but I do not want to increase it, can't I do something else like print the numbers on the page or adjust where the numbers go ?

Comment: What about adding `includefoot` in your [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) options?

Comment: @Werner when I do that it gets huge (like 2 cms)

Comment: Ah footskip=0cm solved it

Comment: @statquant, this solve your problem only partly. At printing of document can happen that number will not be printed, or the printer drawer will shrink page size and by this increase borders. Probably you need to decide for some compromise for bottom margin (slightly increase it).

Comment: @Zarko that's fine the documents are not supposed to be printed. What is wrong though is tha the first page with the title still has the page number centered instead of right

Comment: `thispagestyle{fancy}` directly after `\maketitle`.

Comment: @Zarko Do you want to add an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B, no, about OP question I already say all in my comments. I not intend to change it to an answer, since OP is happy with solution he foud. I suggest to close question as solved by comment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because OP found solutions himself by help of other comments.

Comment: @Zarko this is not off topic, and self solutions are encouraged

Comment: @statquant, well, it is solved by comments, as far I can see.  of course you  can write own answer, please do this!